# Using std::unique_ptr with standard containers

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, unique-ptr

I've been looking for a way to do safe vectors and maps of dynamic pointers, when I realized C++11 adds `unique_ptr`s. I looked into how to use them on Google, but have been unsuccessful in looking for details. What I need to know are the following:

1. What, exactly, is different between pointers and `unique_ptr`s besides automatic memory collection?
2. How would I go about removing a `unique_ptr` from a vector or map? Is there any special code I have to use besides erasing the iterator?

Comment: Is unique_ptr an essential condition?
If safety is your purpose, std::shared_ptr might be an alternative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Nothing. A `unique_ptr` is just a wrapper around a pointer, which deletes the pointer when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed. It has no overhead (just like the `auto_ptr` template it replaces).
2. Nope -- it will just work. The difficulty actually comes from *inserting* the pointer into the vector or map -- whereas you must *move* the `unique_ptr` into the container.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't quite sure, and couldn't find much on Google, so I'm glad to get an answer.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation, though you might want to note that at most one unique_ptr can point at a resource, while an unboundedly large number of raw pointers can point at a particular resource.

Comment: +1, perhaps adding an example of insertion (especially one showing why move is required) would help.

Answer (score 4):

1. The difference is that unique_ptr obeys move semantics.  Further, as the name suggests, you can't make copies of it.
2. Erasing an element of `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T> >` will effectively delete whatever that pointer pointed at.

Comment: +1 for 2. - obvious when you focus on it, but can be a problem during transitioning from raw pointers to smart pointers, if you only go "half way" with raw pointers pointing to freed memory because an item was removed