# Insert unique_ptr into map, pointer gets destroyed

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap, unique-ptr

I'm having the following (simplified) class:

```cpp
class Operator {
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Operand>> op;

public:
    template <class T>
    void insertOperand(std::string const &s, T o = T()) {
        op.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<StreamOperand>>(
            s, std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(o)))
        );
    }

    void setOperandsValue(std::string const &o, int v) {
        op.find(o)->second->setValue(v);
    }
};
```

Inserting a new `Operand` works without any problems. However, when the function returns the destructor gets called and thus the `map` does not contain any object when calling `setOperandsValue`. I've observed this using DDD: at the end of `insertOperand` `Operator::~Operator()` is called.

After looking at [Using std::unique_ptr with STL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4637442/172695), I introduced (better: used) `std::move` but either it's not placed correctly or I am missing something (highly probable due to lack of knowledge). I'm not using `map::emplace` because it's not available.

**Edit:** The destructor call is valid, since it's destroying `new T(o)`. Anyway, the `map` remains empty when entering `setOperandsValue`.

**Edit #2:** On entering `setOperandsValue` and performing `op.find(o)` the result is `op.end`, i.e. entry not found although I've added it before.

Comment: try _insert(std::move(std::pair<key, std::move(ptr)))_, as _insert(pair<...>)_ triggers another level of copying

Comment: what tells you that the destructor gets called? And, which destructor?

Comment: I've traced it with DDD / GDB, at the end of `insertOperand` `Operand::~Operand()` gets called.

Comment: The `o` parameter gets destructed at the end of `insertOperand`. Is that the destructor call you see?

Comment: That's OK, because you're making a `new` T (assuming T is Operand), which is a copy.

Comment: @interjay Yes, then it's valid as juanchopanza said. However, the map is empty afterwards.

Comment: What do you mean by "I introduced std::move"? You can't add types/method/whatever to std namespace, it's forbidden.

Comment: @Simone I just didn't use `std::move` before thus making a copy which is not allowed.

Comment: Not related to your problem - but why do you pass the strings by non-const reference?

Comment: @Henrik this is a mistake, sorry.

Comment: The call to `std::move` in `std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(o)))` is completely unnecessary -- `std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(o))` is a temporary and thus already an rvalue.

Comment: @ildjarn thanks for the hint, I'm fixing this in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your pointer is getting destroyed. What you are seeing here:

```
template <class T>
void insertOperand(std::string &s, T o = T()) {
    op.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<StreamOperand>>(
        s, std::move(std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(o)))
    );
}
```

is the destruction of `o`, after it has been used to construct the heap allocated `T` used in the `unique_ptr`.

The map being empty is not a symptom of the pointer being destroyed. If this were the case (the pointer being destroyed), you would have an entry in the map for a given key, with an invalid unique_ptr.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense to me, however the `map` is empty when entering `setOperandsValue`.

Comment: @SebastianDressler then you have a different problem :-). but are you *sure* it is empty?

Comment: Yep. When entering `setOperandsValue` and for instance performing `op.find(...)` the result is `op::end` and the map is empty.

Comment: @SebastianDressler well, it looks like it is nothing to do with your unique_ptrs then. The insert would only fail if you already had an entry with the same key.

Comment: This is the crucial point, thanks. The call to the class containing the map was wrong.